# How to run power automate on alternative weeks?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have two power automate flows. Which I want to schedule to run alternatively e.g. if Flow X executes this week then next week Flow Y executes and Flow X shouln't. Means both flow biweekly but alternatively.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Yes, you just need to build it into the logic. You need to have to create a weekly flow and check if it is every other weekend somehow. Something like add(div(dayOfYear(utcNow()),7),1)

Answer (score 0):

You can set each flow to run biweekly like this:

[image: Scheduled cloud flow]

As you can see, you can set the start date, and then the repetition. In the screen shot you can see I set it to run each 2 weeks on Monday.

You can set your first flow to start, let's say, today, to run each 2 weeks on Monday; then you go to your second flow and set it the same, but set the start date as one week from now.